# How can i read the value of round slider using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a round slider which i have made with the help of some websites. Now I try to read the current value of slider and store value in database. But i am struggling to get the slider value. By default, the slider shows the value. But  could not use it. I need to store this value in variable and use it further. Can someone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery roundSlider - JS Bin</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.css">
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>roundSlider</h2>  
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="range"></div>
</body>
</html>


$("#slider").roundSlider(
{
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        sliderType: "min-range",
        slide: function(event, ui) { 
          alert(ui.value);
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: Without being able to see 'roundslider.js', it's likely a guess, but have you tried:  `$("#slider").roundSlider("value")` ?

Comment: Yes it is. http://roundsliderui.com/document.html#getValue **getValue() :** Without any parameter, it will return the current slider value.

Comment: slider_value = ui.value;
               $("#range").html(slider_value);

Comment: I used the above line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the value has changed, You can determine by a change event

```
change( event, ui )
```

1. event (event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler)
2. ui : handle(representing the handle that was changed) , handleIndex(numeric index of the handle that was moved),value(current value of the slider.)

You have to write change event like this

```
$("#slider").roundSlider(
{
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        width: 30,
        step: 1,
        sliderType: "min-range",
         change: function (args) {
                console.log(args.value);
            $('#range').html(args.value)
         }        
    }
);
```

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/hc3a2k3q/) here

Comment: Yeah It works!!! But when i try to create alert, it displays as [object object] instead of value

Comment: The alert box displays only specific the text. It converts an object to string but the alert function does not understand objects.so if you really want to alert object write like this `alert (JSON.stringify(args)); ` or use console.log(args).@nawas

Answer (score 0):

append this event handler ...

```
$("#slider").roundSlider({
    change: function (e) {
        console.log(e.value);
    }
});
```

when you only reads the value on submit etc. you can read it directly, in other cases it is possible to read the value while change isn´t finished

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Can use the `drag` event and outside by using `$("#slider").roundSlider("option", "value")`  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/rkqecnut/#&togetherjs=eSbVC6oHk3)

JS:

```
$("#slider").roundSlider(
{
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        sliderType: "min-range",
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(this.getValue());
        },
        slide: function(event, ui) { 
          alert(ui.value);
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: I can get the value inside the slider. But can i store this as a variable? for example, var slidervalue = something

Comment: you can read the value anywhere by using `$("#slider").roundSlider("option", "value")`